# Ignore blanks or values of 0 in column X

Tags: excel, vba

Currently if there is a blank/0 in a cell in column X, that trigger a return of YYY. I need this code to ignore cases when it finds a blank cell or value 0 in column X

```
Sub Macro()
   
Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "General"
    
  Dim lr As Long  

  lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  With Range("K8:K" & lr)

    .Formula = Replace("=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(A$8:A$#,""mmyy"")=TEXT(A8,""mmyy"")),--(S$8:S$#=S8),--(X$8:X$#=X8))" _

        & "=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(A$8:A$#,""mmyy"")=TEXT(A8,""mmyy"")),--(S$8:S$#=S8)),"""",""YYY"")", "#", lr)

    .Value = .Value

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

This is just pseudo-code (not tested, obviously), but I believe you're looking for something like:

```
for each c in Range("K8:K" & lr).Cells
  if (c.Value <> "") and (c.Value <> 0) then
    c.Formula = ...
  end if
next
```